# Pimcore: Fresh installation, backend not loading

Tags: http-status-code-403, pimcore

I wanted to try out Pimcore for the first time today. After alot of setup I've managed to install the [demo-basic-twig template](https://pimcore.com/docs/5.x/Development_Documentation/Getting_Started/Installation.html#page_3-Basic-Demo-Package-Twig-Templates) with composer.

Now I've tried to access the backend via /admin. The first thing I've noticed is that there seems to be no CSS-file loading:

[image: CSS-file not loading?]

Now I thought whatever might just be a bug or something but when I try to log into the backend with the user I created it just shows a blank page with a loader without anything happening:

[image: 2. Pimcore error]

My console just returns a bunch of 403-errors:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) | jquery-3.3.1.min.js:1 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) | icons.css:1
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) | leaflet.css:1
```

I guess I've did something wrong in my installation?

Comment: It seems like your nginx or apache configuration is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like assets are not installed. Try: bin/console assets:install.

Answer (score 3):

My issue was fixed by following the commands below (for Windows):

- php bin/console pimcore:deployment:classes-rebuild -d -c
- php bin/console assets:install web
- php bin/console cache:clear
- restart xampp.

Best Of Luck!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't have permission to open assets folder. So if you are on linux Machine follow this commands inside your pimcore project directory

`sudo chown -R $USER:www-data .`
`sudo chmod -R 777 .`

If you have pimcore <6
`php bin/console assets:install --symlink --relative`

If you have pimcore >=6
`php bin/console assets:install web --symlink --relative`

If you are in windows machine

If you have pimcore <6
`php bin/console assets:install --symlink --relative`

If you have pimcore >=6
`php bin/console assets:install web --symlink --relative`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to add the .htaccess (as provided by pimcore) in /Public folder.
Then run `php bin/console assets:install`